# Authentication with Twitter using the Twitter access token on Azure (using iOS Twitter reverse Auth)

Tags: ios, authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently working on an iOS app which will (if I can figure out this problem) use Azure as backend. The user is supposed to login with their iOS account which they already setup on their iOS device. I than use reverse authentication (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) to get the user's access token and I would like to use said access token to login the user.

I tried using (Swift snippet)

```
let tokenDictionary = ["access_token": "<token-I-got>"];

client.loginWithProvider("twitter", token: tokenDictionary.bridgeToObjectiveC(), completion: {(user: MSUser!, error: NSError?) in

        if let user = user? {

            print(user.userId)

        } else if let error = error? {

            print(error)

        }

})
```

but the only thing the API returns is:

> POST of Twitter token is not supported.

Any ideas how I could get this to work or do I have to switch away from Azure to something different? (And using the webview for login is not an option, as we have this nice already accounts on iOS already setup with the credentials).

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently supported by Azure Mobile Services. You can upvote the feature request [here](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services/suggestions/4123328-add-support-for-client-side-twitter-authentication).